# Solving the function $f(\frac{x+8y}{9})=\frac{f(x)+8f(y)}{9}$

Tags: functions

Let $f(\frac{x+8y}{9})=\frac{f(x)+8f(y)}{9}$ for all real $x$ & $y$. If $f'(0)$ exist and equal to $2$ and $f(0) = –5$, then $f(7)$ is equal to

(1) 3

(2) 7

(3) 5

(4) 9

There are some formulas that need to be considered while solving it

If x, y are independent variables, then:

(i) $f\left( {xy} \right) = f\left( x \right) + f\left( y \right) \Rightarrow f\left( x \right) = k\ell nx$  or $f\left( x \right) = 0$ .

(ii)  $f\left( {xy} \right) = f\left( x \right)f\left( y \right) \Rightarrow f\left( x \right) = {x^n};n \in R$

(iii)  $f\left( {x + y} \right) = f\left( x \right)f\left( y \right) \Rightarrow f\left( x \right) = {a^{kx}}$

(iv) $f\left( {x + y} \right) = f\left( x \right) + f\left( y \right) \Rightarrow f\left( x \right) = kx$, where $k$ is a constant.

(v)  $f\left( x \right).f\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right) = f\left( x \right) + f\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right) \Rightarrow f\left( x \right) = 1 \pm {x^n};n \in N$

Not able to solve it

Comment: $f(x)=2x-5$ is a solution.

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes we get the correct answer but how do we prove it

Comment: The official answer is $f(7)=9$

Comment: What do we need to prove?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that exactly one of the given options is correct, then it must be $f(7)=9$. This is because (as mentioned), all linear functions satisfy the given equation, so in particular $f(x)=2x-5$ (the only linear function satisfying $f(0)=-5,f'(0)=2$).

But... assuming the options are correct feels a bit like cheating, what if in fact there is a non-linear solution? It turns out there is none, i.e. all solutions are linear. For this we first show that $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)$ is additive, i.e. it satisfies [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$. Then under some additional condition we know its solutions are $g(x)=ax$ (hence $f(x)=ax+b$ for some $a,b$). In this case we are given $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, hence $f$ continuous at a point, and so is $g$ - this is one of the sufficient conditions.

So let $g(x):=f(x)-f(0)$. Clearly $g(0)=0$ and
$$g\left(\frac{x+8y}{9}\right)=\frac{g(x)+8g(y)}{9}.\tag{1}$$
From $y=0$ we get $g(\frac{x}{9})=\frac{g(x)}{9}$. Applying this to $(1)$ we get
$$g(x+8y)=g(x)+8g(y).\tag{2}$$
Now $y=\frac{y}{8}$ gives
$$g(x+y)=g(x)+8g\left(\frac{y}{8}\right).\tag{3}$$
Here $x=0$ gives $g(y)=8g(\frac{y}{8})$, and substituting back to $(3)$ we get
$$
g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)
$$
as required.

Answer (score 0):

Any linear function of the form $f(x) = ax + b$ satisfies the functional equation, which can be verified by substituting $ax + b$ for $f(x)$. Now, $f'(0) = a = 2$ and $f(0) = b = -5$. Thus $f(x) = 2x - 5 \implies f(7) = 9$.